# Join Two Temp Table With Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, full-outer-join

I want join two temp tables with Full outer join but doesn't work properly
and allways just show #RMS values without #RMB !!

where and what's wrong in this code?

( #RMS without null )

```
create table #RMS 
(
    [Year] int,
    [Month] int,
    sTAccount bigint,
    sRemaining bigint
)
insert into #RMS(Year,Month,sTAccount,sRemaining)
select
    YEAR(Date) [Year],
    DATEPART(MONTH,Date) [Month],
    sum(TAccount) sTAccount,
    sum(Remaining) sRemaining
from
    SaleInvoices
group by YEAR(Date),DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
order by YEAR(Date),DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
```

( #RMB without null but sometimes #RMB Month Column Value and #RMS Month Column value is Different )

```
create table #RMB 
(
    [Year] int,
    [Month] int,
    bTAccount bigint,
    bRemaining bigint
)
insert into #RMB(Year,Month,bTAccount,bRemaining)
select
    YEAR(Date) [Year],
    DATEPART(MONTH,Date) [Month],
    sum(TAccount) bTAccount,
    sum(Remaining) bRemaining
from
    BuyInvoices
group by YEAR(Date),DATEPART(MONTH,Date)
order by YEAR(Date),DATEPART(MONTH,Date)

select * from #RMS
Full Outer Join #RMB
on #RMS.Year=#RMB.Year and #RMS.Month=#RMB.Month
group by #RMS.Year, #RMS.Month
order by #RMS.Year, #RMS.Month
```

Thanks For Your Answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong `SELECT` list. Replace `*` with `#RMS.*, #RMB.*` or (better) an explicit list of the fields you want, prefixing their names with the name of the table they come from. This also allows not to repeat the fields you've joined on.